# How to run generic beforeEach with shardTestFiles: true?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I'm using protractor to automate tests for an angular.js application, and I have the following folder structure:

```
└── smoke
    ├── before-each-smoke.js
    └── modules
        ├── abc
        │   └── abc-smoke-test.js
        ├── bcd
        │   └── bcd-smoke-test.js
```

In the `before-each-smoke.js` file I have a simple beforeEach() method with common code to all the `it` of the files inside the modules folder.

If I execute protractor with the capability `shardTestFiles: false`, the code defined in the `before-each-smoke.js`will be executed before each test.

If I turn `shardTestFiles` protractor capability to `true` (with `maxInstances: 5`), the code in `before-each-smoke.js` will not be executed before each test.

Is this a restriction of the parallel test execution provided by protractor/selenium? How can I execute a common `beforeEach` before each `it`, with `shardTestFiles: true`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using any framework like cucumber or jasmine??
As they provide before and after hookups for each feature.
In parallel test execution you cant expect one function to execute each time if it's not hooked up.

Comment: @HardikSheth What do you mean?

Comment: You need to add a `beforeEach` (i.e. if you're using jasmine then http://jasmine.github.io/1.3/introduction.html#section-Setup_and_Teardown) in your spec. This `beforeEach` would include a line to `require(./before-each-smoke.js)`